# debugger keyword not working in javascript file in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

We have a javascript file, it uses the debugger keyword inside a function but Visual Studio 2015 ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a HttpModule which puts a version number on the end of the script link, once this was removed the debugger keyword worked again.

Obviously in production we need this so I've just used a '#if debug flag' to work around the problem

I'm sure we never used to get this problem in VS 2013